# Extract Text Before, After, and In Between Specific Characters

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In my database some keywords are surrounded by the "/" and "\" characters.

On the application end, in ColdFusion, I am trying to extract and separate text that appears in and either before or after a string of text surrounded by the “/” and “\”

So say I have a sentence: My baloney has a first name and it is /HOMER\

1. I want to separate the two so I have one variable that has the string **My baloney has a first name and it is**
2. and another variable that has **HOMER** without the “/” and “\”

Again, the “/” and “\” can appear before or after a string of text, as shown below:

```
/Ash\ Gotta catch’em all
```

.

```
/Nike\ Just do it.
```

.

```
Impossible is nothing. /Adidas\
```

.

> Microsoft is already facing lawsuits related to the just-launched Windows, with an operating system technology designer accusing Microsoft of ripping of its patent for "tiles."
>
> SurfCast, in a complaint filed yesterday in a U.S. District Court in Maine, said Microsoft infringes one of its four patents -- No. 6,724,403 -- by "making, using, selling, and offering to sell devices and software products" covered by SurfCast's patent. That includes mobile devices using the Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 operating systems as well as PCs using /Windows 8\

How can I extract and separate text that appears in and either before or after a string of text surrounded by the “/” and “\” ?

Comment: will you ever have a string of 'my /baloney\ is named homer' ? where there is text before and after the / and \ ?

Comment: Just seen the question states _"either before or after"_ - implying it can't be both - in which case List~ functions are probably the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the separate text is always at the start/end you can simply use [ListFirst](http://cfdocs.org/ListFirst) like so:

```
<cfset First = ListFirst(Text,'/\') />
<cfset Last = ListLast(Text,'/\') />
```

And you'll have both parts in separate variables. To work out which is which, you'll want to do a [`Left(Text,1)`](http://cfdocs.org/Left) to determine if the original text started with `/` or not.

Otherwise, you can extract the /...\ text with [rematch](http://cfdocs.org/rematch):

```
<cfset Slashes = rematch('/[^\\]+(?=\\)',Text) />
```

Which returns an array of matches starting with `/` - you can't avoid capturing the first slash in CF's regex (no lookbehind support), but you can remove it afterwards with [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

```
<cfset Slashes[x] = Slashes[x].substring(1) />
```

<sub>(Use `1` instead of `x` if only ever one result, otherwise you'll need a loop.)</sub>

To get the text without this value you can can then use a simple [replace](http://cfdocs.org/replace) like so:

```
<cfset Unslashed = replace(Text,'/#Slashes[x]#\','') />
```